# Foreach error variable cannot identified

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

i have this function

```
function c_del()
{
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $uname  = $session_data['username'];
    $query  = $this->user_m->viewDetail($uname);
    foreach($query as $row)
        {
            $username=$row->username;
        }
    $id_calon_reg=$_GET['a'];
    $query1 = $this->candidate_m->del_calon($id_calon_reg);
    $query3 = $this->candidate_m->search_calon($id_calon_reg);
    foreach($query3 as $row)
        {
            $foto_calon=$row->foto_calon;
        }
    unlink($foto_calon);
    $query2 = $this->candidate_m->viewAll();
    $data=array(
        "query"=>$query2,
        "username"=>$username
    );
    $this->load->helper(array('form'));
    $this->load->view('candidate_view',$data);
}
```

i want to unlink the path stored in $foto_calon, but i get this error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: foto_calon
>
> Filename: controllers/candidate.php
>
> Line Number: 67

line 67 is where i call unlink function.

but I already define the variable $foto_calon in foreach.

the first foreach when i want to store the username into $username its success but got error in the second foreach.

i can't find out what's the problem. can anybody tell me?

Comment: Instead of editing title with `[SOLVED]` you should [accept the answer that worked for you as solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This is how SO works. [Further reading](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for understanding how StackOverflow works

Comment: Instead of adding `solved` to the title, you can accept an answer by clicking the corresponding tick.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
foreach($query3 as $row)
{
   $foto_calon=$row->foto_calon;
}
```

with

```
if(is_array($query3)) {
    foreach($query3 as $row)
    {
        $foto_calon=$row['foto_calon'];
    }
}
```

And if you want to unlink **each row** of foto_calon in the result array then put that unlink in this foreach loop like

```
if(is_array($query3)) {
    foreach($query3 as $row)
    {
        $foto_calon=$row['foto_calon'];
        unlink($foto_calon);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the unlink into the foreach, like so :

```
    $id_calon_reg=$_GET['a'];
    $query1 = $this->candidate_m->del_calon($id_calon_reg);
    $query3 = $this->candidate_m->search_calon($id_calon_reg);
    foreach($query3 as $row)
        {
            $foto_calon=$row->foto_calon;
            unlink($foto_calon);
        }
```

Comment: @user2467703 Please mark it as resolve and upvote it if it was usefull for you